# Remove whitespace and quote marks around option

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm manually rendering a choice field.

```
                         <select name="basisofpricing" id="id_basisofpricing">

                            {% for value, object in form3.basisofpricing.field.choices %}

                                <option                                             
                                        value="{{value}}"
                                        {% if form3.basisofpricing.initial.id == value %}
                                           selected
                                        {% endif %}

                                >
                                    {{object.basisofrate}}

                                </option>

                            {% endfor %}

                        </select>
```

When I do this, within the browser, the option, when inspected, has quotes and space around it. For example, if Red was one of the options, it would appear like this when being inspected within the browser:

```
<option value="2">
    "

       Red

    "
</option>
```

This spacing and these quotes do not appear on the options' text when I just render the choice field with {{form3.basisofpricing}}.

Any thoughts on how I can remove the white spacing and quotes around the option text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this exactly, without new line or space.

```
<option value="{{value}}" {% if form3.basisofpricing.initial.id == value %} selected {% endif %}>{{object.basisofrate}}</option>
```